# jquery: need some function that will empty all the <input> value attribute (that inside form) except inputs that type is hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input, hidden

I need to empty all the values, all the checked boxes and all the selected items (reset the values inside  )
except the inputs with type="hidden" attribute.

```html
<form id="formname">
<input type="text" value="1232423"/>
<input type="password" value="abcdefgh"/>
<input type="file"/>
<textarea>some inputed text</textarea>
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked"  />
<select>
<option>a</option>
<option selected="selected">b</option>
<option>c</option>
</select>

<input type="hidden" value="storeddata1"/>
<input type="hidden" value="storeddata2"/>
<input type="hidden" value="storeddata3"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this  (https://codepen.io/AlibiGhazi/pen/XWddyPR)

```js
$(':input','#formname')  
  .not(':hidden')
  .val('')
  .prop('checked', false)
  .prop('selected', false);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formname">
<input type="text" value="1232423"/>
<input type="password" value="abcdefgh"/>
<input type="file"/>
<textarea>some inputed text</textarea>
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked"  />
<select>
<option>a</option>
  
  
<option selected="selected">b</option>
<option>c</option>
</select>

<input type="hidden" value="storeddata1"/>
<input type="hidden" value="storeddata2"/>
<input type="hidden" value="storeddata3"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also make use of form.reset(). This method when called on a form element, resets all its children to have the initial value that were given to these children.